# How to use Map object with observables?

Tags: typescript, dictionary, rxjs, observable

I want to use a map object with observables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

The Map approach is in order to increase the performance in the search and access to the values.

But I don't have idea how use observables with Map.

```
const contacts = new Map();
contacts.set('Jessie', {phone: "213-555-1234", address: "123 N 1st Ave"})
contacts.has('Jessie') // true
contacts.get('Hilary') // undefined
contacts.set('Hilary', {phone: "617-555-4321", address: "321 S 2nd St"})
contacts.get('Jessie') // {phone: "213-555-1234", address: "123 N 1st Ave"}
contacts.delete('Raymond') // false
contacts.delete('Jessie') // true
console.log(contacts.size) // 1
```

Comment: Maps and observables are completly unrelated topics. So I don't see what you mean with *"use observables with Map"*. What is the issue here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? emite a value each time the map changes? or just emit the entire map once?